# Measure time taken by a function in C got always 0.000000

Tags: c

I read an article form [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-program-in-c/).The code shows a funciton to measure the time function cost.

In my machine ,I always got 0.000000  no matter how long I press enter.

I print t = clock() - t;  t always equal to 0.00000,I rewrite the statement to this,still got 0.000000.

```
clock_t m;
m = clock() - t;
```

gcc version in centos7

```
[root@localhost log]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
/* Program to demonstrate time taken by function fun() */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 

// A function that terminates when enter key is pressed 
void fun() 
{ 
    printf("fun() starts \n"); 
    printf("Press enter to stop fun \n"); 
    while(1) 
    { 
        if (getchar()) 
            break; 
    } 
    printf("fun() ends \n"); 
} 

// The main program calls fun() and measures time taken by fun() 
int main() 
{ 
    // Calculate the time taken by fun() 
    clock_t t; 
    t = clock(); 
    fun(); 
    t = clock() - t; 
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds 

    printf("fun() took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine here. Did you try to investigate this? Did you try to printf the intermediate values and variables involved?

Comment: If `clock()` happens to return "number of 100 millisecond ticks", then (if you're unlucky) the function could take 99.99 milliseconds and it'd end up truncated to zero.

Comment: `clock()` returns CPU time (of which you probably aren't using much), not wall clocks. use `time()` instead (or make the loop break on `getchar() == 'a'` or similar and feed it a bunch of newlines before 'a').

Comment: Hrm - could change it to `printf("fun() took between %f and %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken - 1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, time_taken + 1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); `. That'd give you a better idea of how precise your `clock()` is.

Comment: I'll also point out the reason you aren't using much CPU time is that `getchar()` is blocking. You can also use `clock_gettime()` (or `gettimeofday()`) for more accurate wall clocks, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this instead:

```
unsigned int t=time(0);
fun();
unsigned int result=time(0)-t; // result is the time taken by fun
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to measure "CPU time used" (and not "wall clock time spent waiting for user to press a key"), then...

Imagine if the OS has a timer that generates an IRQ 10 times per second, and the IRQ handler just does `ticks++`; and `clock()` is just `return ticks;`. In this case, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` would be 10.

Now, if you call `clock()` once just before the timer IRQ occurs and again immediately after the timer IRQ occurs, the difference between the values returned might be 1 (equal to 100 ms) even significantly less time passed between calls to `clock()`.

Alternatively; if you call `clock()` once immediately after the timer IRQ occurs and again just before the timer IRQ occurs again, the difference between the values returned might be 0, even significantly more time passed between calls to `clock()`.

Essentially, the difference between values returned by `clock()` is "up to `1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` sooner than you think" and "up to `1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` longer than you think".

Note that the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is implementation defined. Depending on various things (which version of which OS running on which hardware, with which C library) `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` can be anything, and could be as low as 10 and could be as high has 4 billion.

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` measures the CPU time, that is the time that the processor has been active. You may want to measure wall clock time instead, which is the number of seconds from the start to the end of the function run:

```
struct timeval start;
gettimeofday(&start, 0); 
fun();
struct timeval end;
gettimeofday(&end, 0); 
double time_taken = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)
    + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)*1e-6;
```

To make this work, you must also include `<sys/time.h>`